# How to covert .txt file into .xls file in UNIX?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

My ETL outputs 6 txt file and I need to covert those txt files into xls file.

And I have additional requirement, first 3 txt files should be copied into one xls file (in 3 different sheets) and remaining 3 txt file into anothel xls file.

File Format:

The Delimiter is tab

```
A   B   C

D   E   F
```

Comment: what is the data format in text file?

Comment: The Delimiter is tab
A B C
D E F

Comment: Are there blank lines like you show too? And why don't you just import the CSV file into Excel as is?

Comment: I need to automate this process.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35433718/edit) and I'll retract my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the txt files to csv files (make a sed or tr command to change tab for comma.

With tr command

```
tr '\t' ',' < file.txt > file2.txt
```

Then convert the csv do DOS format

```
unix2dos my_csv_file.csv
```

The use the command [ssconvert](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssconvert) to convert to xls

Put all theses command in a script and "voila"

Comment: have to be careful about fields that contain commas and/or double quotes. CSV is surprisingly tricky to get right. Excel can happily read csv files, so I'd stop after unix2dos.